# Simple SQL select not working on DocumentDB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have this very simple test document stored in DocumentDb:

```
{
  "DocumentDbTest_Countries": {
      "@country": "C24105130563",
      "@language": "C24105130563",
      "@countryCode": 1663405662,
      "@version": "2015-08-24T08:51:32:030.6165"
  },
  "id": "729607bd-38c5-2a96-0bc4-371a0a5bca4a"
}
```

Which I can find easily using the *Document Explorer*, and, also using the following Sql query in the *Query Explorer*:

```
SELECT * FROM DocumentDbTest_Countries c
```

But surprisingly when i run the following SQL query, it can't find the result:

```
SELECT * FROM DocumentDbTest_Countries c where c.country = 'C24105130563'
```

Can someone please guide me as to what I am doing wrong in the above SQL query?? I tried using double quotes instead of single but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Since @ is a special character, you have to escape it with the Dictionary-like [] operator. For example, run the query as:

```
SELECT * FROM DocumentDbTest_Countries c where c["@country"] = 'C24105130563'
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Its because of the @ sign present in the attributes.

Strangely I am using DocumentDB SDK to insert the data and those @ signs in the attributes are inserted by it. :(

Now have to find a way to remove the @ sign from the inserts.

Comment: Can you please post the code sample with the DocumentDB SDK?

Comment: Sure @AravindRamachandran

I was trying to convert the following xml to JSON and save it to DocumentDB:
<DocumentDbTest.Countries country="C25103657983" language="C25103657983" countryCode="383388823" version="2015-08-25T08:36:59:982.3552" />
Now the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode adds the @ to the attributes by default, which gets saved as it to the DocumentDB without any issues/warnings. But then you can't search on it afterwards. :(

Comment: Got it, please see how to escape the @ character in queries below.